# git merge - possibility to duplicate commits?

Tags: git

When I create a new branch, do some commits and then merge the branche back to master, I get only one new commit in the main branch which contains all the changes from all commits. Is there a way of merging, where the commits are duplicated into the master branch?

Example:

```
A -- B -- C
 \
  D -- E -- F
```

I want to merge C to F, so that I get the following:

```
A -- B -- C
 \
  D -- B' -- E' -- C' -- F'
```

Or another diagram that shows the same:

```
A -- B ---- C
 \    \      \
  D ----- E ----- F
```

To do that, it would have to modify EVERY SINGLE COMMIT from F back to D, and add the modified versions of the commits I want to merge in. In the end, I wouldn´t get a new commit at all, I would only change very much commits.

Is there something that can achieve such a behavior?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `git cherry-pick` to duplicate commits into another branch. There is also `git rebase` which may or may not be more suitable for your task.

Note that your second graph shows a state that isn't called a merge even if you call it so.

Comment: git rebase is exactly what I wanted :D Thanks!